# Bottom Navigation Bar is completely white, how to fix?

Tags: flutter, dart, navigationbar

My `BottomNavigationBar` is completely white. It works fine when there is `3` icons but when increased to `4`, the Navbar goes completely white. The tabs can still be selected and changed.

This is the output of the console when the widget is run.

```
ic=null mNaviBarColor -15724014 mIsGetNaviBarColorSuccess true , NavVisible : true , NavTrans : false
```

This is the build of the Navbar:

```
_bottomNavChildren[_currentIndex],
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
    onTap: onTabTapped,
    currentIndex: _currentIndex,
    items: [
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.search),
        title: Text('Browse'),
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.message),
        title: Text('Messages'),
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.person_outline),
        title: Text('Profile'),
```

And this is the `List` widget that points to the relevant indexed classes.

```
  int _currentIndex = 0;
  final List<Widget> _bottomNavChildren = [
    BrowsePage(),
    MessagesPage(),
    ProfilePage(),
  ];
```

Anyone know what the issue is?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From flutters [official documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html):

> BottomNavigationBarType.fixed, the default when there are less than
>   four items. The selected item is rendered with the selectedItemColor
>   if it's non-null, otherwise the theme's ThemeData.primaryColor is
>   used. If backgroundColor is null, The navigation bar's background
>   color defaults to the Material background color, ThemeData.canvasColor
>   (essentially opaque white).
>
> BottomNavigationBarType.shifting, the default when there are four or
>   more items. If selectedItemColor is null, all items are rendered in
>   white. The navigation bar's background color is the same as the
>   BottomNavigationBarItem.backgroundColor of the selected item. In this
>   case it's assumed that each item will have a different background
>   color and that background color will contrast well with white.

Comment: Right. Adding `BottomNavigationBarType.fixed` for the `type` solved it. Thanks.